# How do I trigger something when I don't enter or left of a Geofence

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, location, android-geofence

i'm using geofences in my app

```
private fun CriaFronteirasDeGeofencingList(){
    geofencingClient?.addGeofences(ConfiguracoesNovaFronteira(), GeofencePendingIntent())?.run {
        addOnSuccessListener {
            // Geofences added
        }
        addOnFailureListener {
            println("error: " + it.localizedMessage.toString())

        }
    }
}

private fun ConfiguracoesNovaFronteira(): GeofencingRequest {

    return GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
        setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
        addGeofences(geofenceList)
    }.build()
}

private fun GeofencePendingIntent () : PendingIntent {
    val intent = Intent(context, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}

    private fun ConfiguraListaDeFronteiras(idEmpresa : String, latitude : Double, longitude : Double, raioEmMetros : Float){

        listaDeFronteiras.add(
            Geofence.Builder()
                .setRequestId(idEmpresa)
                .setCircularRegion(
                    latitude,
                    longitude,
                    raioEmMetros
                )
                .setNotificationResponsiveness(SecondsToMillisseconds(10))
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build()
        )
    }
```

in 10 seconds to 10 seconds this analyse if I entered or I left of a geofence and if i do that my PendingIntent is triggered
but if i don't left or entered, what's triggered? Nothing. I want trigger something when my geofence analyzes if I entered or left of a geofence but I didn't, how i can do that?

This is how i access the user location:

```
private fun RequestLocationUpdatesController(context: Context){
    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        locationRequest.interval = 20000;
        locationRequest.fastestInterval = 20000;
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        client.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, getlocationCallback(), null)
}


private fun getLocationCallBack () : LocationCallback{
        return object : LocationCallback() {
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    //println("null value")
                    return;
                }

                for (location: Location in locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    //println("location handle");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `but if i don't left or entered, what's triggered? Nothing.` Well, that is ok. Dont complain.

Comment: `I want trigger something when my geofence analyzes if I entered or left of a geofence but I didn't, ` You do not have to trigger anything yourself. If you enter or leave a geofence an event will be triggered automatically.

Comment: I know, but in my case, I need register when my geofence searched if I entered or left of a geofence but It return false. What alternatives do I have to do this?

Comment: I only see you adding some geofences to a list. I see nothing concerning a location-change.

Comment: Ok, i'm using requestLocationUpdates, I was thinking it'snt important, but now I added the code to my post